# Why Is It Called Memoization?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

`Memoization` is a programming technique where the results of expensive function calls are stored and reused, preventing redundant computations and improving performance.

**Sample Memoization**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Fibonacci {

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> memory = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = calculateFibonacci(5);
        System.out.println("Fibonacci number at position 5 is: "  + result);
    }

    private static int calculateFibonacci(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) { return n;}
        if (memory.containsKey(n)) { return memory.get(n); }
        
        int fib = calculateFibonacci(n - 1) + calculateFibonacci(n - 2);
        memory.put(n, fib);

        return fib;
    }
}
```

Clearly defined by the explanation and exemplified by the example, this technique involves creating a cache for results and memorizing values, utilizing memory. In everyday language, this behavior is also referred to as memorization.The omission of the "r" in the term is simply unnecessary and can make the naming definition vague.

***I am wondering why this technique is called "memoization" instead of "memorization"?***

Comment: [Memoization in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: just a side note memoization has nothing to do with dynamic programming its a technique (that can be used there) and another one English is not very good language for expressing technical stuff its just used "globaly" because its "easy" to learn because of its simplicity so I would not think too much about adding irregularities to terms to distinguish something ...

Comment: Fun fact: the memo that introduced the concept of "memo functions" actually used the word "memorising" rather than "memoising". (And I don't know where Wikipedia got its etymology from. It seems highly debatable to me.)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly because it's NOT "memorization" and has a specific meaning beyond simply memorizing something. I.e., you're memorizing something **for a specific purpose** (a performance benefit, not simply storing information).

According to Wikipedia, on [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (emphasis mine):

> The term "memoization" was coined by Donald Michie in 1968 and is derived from the Latin word "memorandum" ("to be remembered"), usually truncated as "memo" in American English, and thus carries the meaning of "turning [the results of] a function into something to be remembered". **While "memoization" might be confused with "memorization" (because they are etymological cognates), "memoization" has a specialized meaning in computing.**

While [memorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorization) is generically

> the process of committing something to memory